# Excel: Check cell for date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Short story short:

I want to check the cell C21 if it contains a date. I can't use VB cause it's deactivated by GPO.

Used this from [this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/formula-to-check-if-it-is-a-date/39c833d6-94d3-4c83-b3f6-117a5fd20344)

**D21 contains this:**

```
=WENN(ISTZAHL(DATWERT(C21));"date";"no date")
in english
=IF(ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(C21))...
```

**C21 this:**

```
=HEUTE() # in english: =TODAY() Maybe other dates later, but allways in the correct format
```

but it allways returns "no date"

Comment: I've had a deeper look to the site you linked. There it's stated "if your date is formatted as text", and you create an example where you have a date but not formatted as text, it's obvious it won't work. Also you've commented "It's less a check for a valid date then a check if there is anything at all.", please clarify your question and add some sample data to help us understanding. Also please make sure you've understood what you've linked, there is a lot of useful information there.

Comment: will update my answer on monday since the formula is stored at work and i cant access it for now

Answer (score 14):

Use this: `=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",C21))="D",..,..)`. Learn more about `CELL` formula [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB).

In your example `=TODAY()` already a real date and not a date  stored as text, so doesn't make too much sense to use `DATEVALUE` there.

### Update

Here are some example dates and how `CELL` recognize them:

```
format          value           output
dd/mmmm/yyyy    12/June/2015    D1
dd/mm/yyyy      12/06/2015      D1
yyyy            2015            G
general         2015            G
dd/mm           12/06           D2
mmmm            June            G
dd mmmm yyyy    12 June 2015    G
```

Note: `CELL` is not volatile, so if the format of source cell is changed it won't be refreshed automatically, you need to either recalculate your sheet / book, either open the formula and press enter (also automatice recalculation initiated by any other volatile formula will cause it to refresh).

Comment: it depends on how this 5 looks like in the cell:). if you see `5` than it won't be considered as date, but `05/01/1900` has also the value of 5 and in this case it will be considered as true.

Comment: I get an "invalid" with this formular

Comment: what do you mean "invalid"? the formula is not yet complete, you need to put your values instead of `...`s. Also I don't know how e.g. `"format"` need to be changed in a german environment, and unfortunately I can't help you with that.

Comment: Interesting, didn't think about this usage of `CELL()`. Your formula could get false positives if it's formatted as *time*, isn't it? Also, it seems to me that if you get back and forth from *time* to *general* then *time* formatting, `CELL("format",...)` returns `G` instead of `D8`. Need to investigate further...

Comment: @dan: Time vs date: It's really question of fine tuning which could be done with more information on the problem: You can use also the right digit of the code, our just check whether value is bigger than 1 ... Switching back and forth between number formats: I'd even users don't know whether a value is date or not, how do you expect it from excel?

Comment: This only works for SOME data formats, for example the "short date", but not for others, for example the "long date" from the format drop down.

Comment: CELL only works if the format is explicitly one of the types listed in the link in the answer. (Read the list carefully - it matters a LOT.) Dates formatted `yyyy-mm-dd` aren't considered dates by CELL, regardless of whether it's formatted using the list of available formats or as a custom format. I entered a date with CTRL-semicolon in a cell default-formatted as General; CELL didn't consider that a date. CELL still doesn't work on Excel for the Web as of Aug 2022. Its limitations + unpredictability of data entry means it only works in situations so tightly controlled as to be unreliable.

Answer (score 11):

Use this formula, the expression will return TRUE if cell A1 contains an invalid date.

```
=ISERROR(DATE(DAY(A1),MONTH(A1),YEAR(A1)))
```

This formula works by evaluating each component part of the date: DAY, MONTH and YEAR and then aggregating them using the DATE function.

ISERROR will the catch any errors by returning TRUE (invalid) otherwise FALSE (valid).

Obviously the date value in cell (A1) must contain values >= 01/01/1900.

Useful for "Conditional Formatting".

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me to identify a problem with a non-date value in a 1.5 million row CSV file. Other answers did not work correctly (in my case).

Comment: The DATE function requires first the year, then the month and then the day, so the formula indicated shall be =ISERROR(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))).

Comment: Any number in A1 will be treated like a date, whether it's formatted as such or not. If I have 1234.56 in A1, the formula as written is false, meaning no error, so it's a date. Really?

Comment: @JonPeltier Is correct. I just tried this to determine which cells in my spreadsheet have dates entered, and which are blank. But it identifies the blanks as dates. Specifically it interprets the blanks as date number "0", and comes up with January 0th, 1900. This approach DOES correctly identify strings as NOT dates, so if you're just trying to distinguish "dates" from strings, it's OK. But won't distinguish "dates" from "numbers" and "blanks".

Answer (score 8):

Excel stores dates as numbers. 1 is 1-Jan-1900.

When it comes to numbers in a cell, Excel cannot tell if a number is meant to be a number or a date.

Today is `11/06/2015` as a date and `42166` as a number.  For the consumer of a spreadsheet, the cell can be formatted to display the number as any number format or as a date. Excel formulas cannot tell whether the number in that cell is "meant" to be a date.

So, there is no Excel formula that you can use in a spreadsheet that will tell you if cell A1 is about 42166 widgets or if contains the date of June-11-2015.

Comment: please have a look to the link in my solution, EXCEL CAN TELL YOU THE FORMATTING!

Comment: It's less a check for a valid date then a check if there is anything at all.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, it does not recognize all date formats as dates, even if they are picked from the date section of the number formatting dialog.

Comment: @teylyn is correct. There is no way to reliably formulaically confirm a date. CELL is too unreliable and fails in most common circumstances. It also doesn't work in Excel for the web, Excel Mobile, and Excel Starter as of Aug 2022. The only thing you can reliably determine is whether the cell contains a number >= 0. Maybe that's your first test in a chain; through other forms of inference, you might guess whether it's a date, but you'll still need human confirmation or force good data hygiene/normalization. I haz a sad.

Answer (score 4):

Some of provided answers, checks cell format, which will not considers cell value, as you can format differently each cell no matter of its content, for checking if a cell value is date you can use this:

```
if(ISERROR(VALUE(c21)),"No Date", ----do staff for Date ----)
```

or shorter version which just will inform you "no date" status. If a date entry is find, it will return its numerical value instead:

```
IFERROR(VALUE(c21),"No Date")
```

hope this helps,
Cheers,
M

Comment: Did not work for me on empty cells

Comment: @cyberponk , Date fields are numbers, this approach used this fact. try to change the format of you date cell to number, what you see? 
if it will still displayed something else, it is probably text "12-3-2021" this could be text or actual date.
you can use Text to column to change them to Date or Number before using this function.

Answer (score 0):

use the following formula ...

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(C21,"mm/dd/yyyy")))),"valid date","invalid date")
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: What if C21 contains the number 5. Is that a date?

Comment: this will evaluate to true for all numbers regardless of the original formatting.

Comment: Not useful: Any number in C21 will be treated like a date, whether it's formatted as such or not. If I have 1234.56 in C21, the formula as written is false, meaning no error, so it's a date. If I have the year 1996, it is treated as the date 18 June 1905. So not the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is a string this method would work.

```
TEXT(DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(AI8,4)),VALUE(MID(TRIM(AI8),4,2)),VALUE(LEFT(AI8,2))),"dd.mm.yyyy") = AI8
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to the discussion that although you can check with a date(year;month;day) it will give you false positives, since the way it works is that it seems to just roll over values that exceed the logical limit, i.e. if you have the date 99-12-35 it will assume that you meant to write Jan 4th 2000, since that is the 35 - the 31 days of December. In other words, you will find some errors, but not all. Same goes for months exceeding 12.

Answer (score 0):

try this formula (depends on date format):

```
=IF(DATE(TEXT(C21;"yyyy");TEXT(C21;"mm");TEXT(C21;"dd"));"contains date";"doesn't")
```

Comment: Do you ask for help with choosing between these two? Do you see a problem with either? Maybe you can find the help you are asking for if you read the explanations which the answer posts here provide? But follow up questions like this should not be put into posts created with "Post Your Answer" button.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31237878)

Comment: Yunnosch, Ike, thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution posted but none of them work if there are empty cells in the date cells, so I added a check to GBGOLC's answer and now it works with empty cells:

```
=IF(NOT(OR(ISBLANK(C21),ISERR(DATE(DAY(C21),MONTH(C21),YEAR(C21))))),"Yes it is a date","Not a date")
```