# Check if a Cell in a Range contains a Date

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to determine if a cell in my range contains a date (any date) and if it does to exit the sub with a message.
The date format looks like this: dd-mmm-yy but is generated by a formula within the cell.

Here is some of my code already written along with some pseudo code of what I want to achieve.

```
Sub RemoveRowButton()
'This Macro deletes a row where the button is clicked.
'Variables
Dim row As Long
Dim varResponse As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



'Message box confirming user is doing the right thing
varResponse = MsgBox("Delete this row? 'Yes' or 'No'", vbYesNo, "Delete Row")
    If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

'Carry on with deleting row.....

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow


*******Pseudo Code *******
'Check if the row to be deleted has a date in the D Column of the range (which is a Row)

'If IsDate **in D column of the Range is ture*** Then
'MsgBox "This Row Contains a Date!"
'End If


'Unprotect sheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="***"

'Delete row on button row
rng.Delete

'Protect sheet again
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="***"

End Sub
```

If you could explain your code/answers too I would be grateful, Thanks.

EDIT:

Thank you for all the help, I have, through trial and error created this which works for me.

```
 Set rng2 = rng.Cells(, 4)
   If IsDate(rng2.Value) Then 'Check Cell for Date
     MsgBox "Warning: This Row Cannot be deleted!"
   Exit Sub
   End If
```

Since I am unfamiliar with VBA I do not know if this is "OKAY" in the sense of best practices. If not and you feel like correcting it please do so.

Comment: are all your dates in column D? What is the cell range? (a 'row' can be very short or verrry long.....)

Comment: Yes all the Dates are in Column D and always will be. The columns/cells in the row extend from A-S

Comment: Essentially I want to check if there is a "Date" in the D column of my range, which is a single row that has data between the first cell which is in column A and the last cell which is in column S.

Comment: The problem is that to Excel, dates are numbers masked in a format that looks like a date.  So if your column also has numbers it will be difficult to separate a date and and a number.  You can use the `Range.NumberFormat` property in conjunction with IsNumeric() to test and that the value is greater than 0.  If ALL pass then most likely it is a date.

Comment: You could use ISERROR (there's an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49279614/1675954)  ) . If there's a possibility of the cell being left empty you could potentially check for null value either..?

Comment: It can be hard to tell, for reasons outlined by @ScottCraner. But maybe if you explained **why** you needdo this, a more appropriate solution can be devised.  Also, what else might be in the cell?

Comment: @Rachel Gallen A solution could be to reverse the logic and check to see if the cell is empty, since I don't want to delete the row if there is a date present. By that logic if there isn't a date or anything in that cell then its "safe" to delete it.

Comment: @J4C3N-14 that's what I was suggesting you do (regarding the null value).. only saw your message now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea for your problem. Install the code in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you wish to have the action (not in a standard module like 'Module1' !!) Note that the code reacts to a double-click in column D from row 2 down to the last used row in **column A**. You can adjust that. Follow the directions in the code itself. I use this method instead of the button you seem to have in every row of your sheet - a matter of preference, but used here for demonstration and to avoid creating buttons.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' 03 Jan 2019

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    R = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row        ' last used row in column A
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(R, 4))       ' used range in column D

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        ' if a cell in Rng as double-clicked:-
        R = Target.Row
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(R, "A"), Cells(R, "S"))
        For Each Cell In Rng
            With Cell
                If IsDate(.Value) Then
                    For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
                        ' check if the Numberformat contains all of "m", "d" and "y"
                        If InStr(1, .NumberFormat, Mid("dmy", i, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For
                    Next i
                    If i = 0 Then                   ' all 3 were found
                        If MsgBox("Do you want to delete row " & R & " ?", _
                                  vbQuestion Or vbYesNo, _
                                  "Click ""No"" to keep the row") = vbYes Then
                            Rows(R).Delete
                        End If
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next Cell
        Cancel = True                               ' ends in-cell editing
    End If
End Sub
```

The code carries out two checks on each cell (A:S). It first checks if its value is a date. Then, presuming it is a number, it checks the cell format. If the NumberFormat includes all of the letters 'm", "d" and "y" it is confirmed as a date and released for deletion before which the user can confirm his intention.
This method may require a little fine tuning. Firstly, if the cell has text date a different second check would have to be carried out. Second, if the date format consists of only 2 of the 3 criteria the test for their presence in the mask must be reduced accordingly. Either of these modifications, or both, could be implemented once the nature of your data is better understood.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers and an example. I do require a button in each row unfortunately. However how you are checking for a date format could be a solution. How best to implement that into my code?

Comment: In your code, 'If IsDate **in D column of the Range is ture*** Then
'MsgBox "This Row Contains a Date!"
corresponds to my code If IsDate(.Value) Then
                    For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
                        ' check if the Numberformat contains all of "m", "d" and "y"
                        If InStr(1, .NumberFormat, Mid("dmy", i, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For
                    Next i
                    If i = 0 Then                   ' all 3 were found

Answer (score 1):

@J4C3N-14 did you try:

```
Sub Test_Date()

    Dim strDate As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        strDate = .Range("A1").Value

        If IsDate(strDate) Then
            'Code
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```