# excel, conditional formatting in other tab

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two tab sheets. I have in the first tab sheet a cell (B21) with a the following conditional formatting code: =ISNUMBER(B21)..then the cell will turn green.

What I want is that cell A1 in the second tab sheet will act the same as cell B21 in the first tab sheet.

I can copy the cell and then paste it in the second tab sheet but then the conditional code in the A1 cell is =ISNUMBER(A1) but I want it to refer to tabsheet 2, which is =ISNUMBER(B21)

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the second tab and select Conditional Formatting, New Rule and select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

Click the range selector button (to the right of the text box with the red arrow). Now select `B21` on the first tab, reclick the range selector button, make your formatting changes and click `OK`.

In the picture below, you can see that the formula refers to `B21` on `Sheet 1`, but is applied to `A1 on`Sheet 2`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks al lot! Do you also happen to know how to do the formula for the following:
If a date in A1 and A2 then turn green.  I thought something like this but that didn't work.

=IF(AND(A1=Number, A2=NUMBER))

Comment: I believe I need 20 reputations for that. Where can I find the "check Mark"? (Ok..I have checked it)

Comment: You want it to turn green if both are dates (any dates) or it's the same date in cell `A1` and `A2`? And both cells turn green or just one?

Comment: Yes, if both are dates (any dates). Can be different, but it has to be a date.

Comment: I don't think you can easily or in all cases. Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778620/excel-check-cell-for-date

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. Is it easier if it are numbers instead of dates?

Comment: By easy, I mean I think you need VBA to do this.