# Return an Array of Only Numbers From a Range With Mixed Datatypes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

- Related to the following screenshot, the formula

  ```
  =IF(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$5),$A$1:$A$5)
  ```

  will evaluate to the following array

  ```
  {1;FALSE;2;44644;3}
  ```

  but I only need it to return the numbers

  ```
  {1;2;3}
  ```
- How can this be achieved (getting rid of the dates and booleans)?
- Note that `ISNUMBER` has already gotten rid of error values and whatnot.
  [image]

**Utilization in VBA**

- Instead of the loop and whatnot in the first procedure I want to simplify by evaluating the correct formula in the second procedure.

**Correct**

```vb
Sub CorrectVBA()
' Result:
' 1
' 2
' 3
   
    Const rgAddress As String = "A1:A5"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(rgAddress)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim Arr() As Double
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Item = Data(r, 1)
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Item) Then
            If Not IsDate(Item) Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To n)
                Arr(n) = Item
            End If
        End If
    Next r
       
    If n = 0 Then Exit Sub
       
    For n = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(n)
    Next n
       
End Sub
```

**Wrong**

- Something like this is what I want to do in this particular case.
- It is wrong because the formula is wrong.

```vb
Sub WrongVBA()
' Result:
'  1
' False
'  2
'  44644
'  3
    
    Const rgAddress As String = "A1:A5"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = ws.Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(" & rgAddress & ")," & rgAddress & ")")
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Debug.Print Data(r, 1)
    Next r
   
End Sub
```

**Final Word**

- Thank you all.
- I have decided to accept objectively **JvdV**'s answer since, if not already, Office 365 is becoming a standard and its new functions make things so much easier.
- Personally, the most useful answers were those of **T.M.** and **Ron Rosenfeld**.
- Also, thanks to **Can.U** and **Domenic**.

Comment: You can return just numbers by  using the `FILTER` function.  But Excel does not have a date data type. Those values are just formatted numbers.  But even checking the Format won't always work because, with a long-date format, the `CELL("format",[reference])` function returns a `G`.  And also that function, in addition to not changing when the format changes,. seems to return the format code of the first cell only when it is supplied a multi-cell range as [reference]. The only `IsDate` function of which I am aware is in VBA.

Comment: I don't have O365, but I didn't mention it so O365 users could also benefit. Is there a way without the `FILTER` function e.g. just returning what isn't `FALSE`? Never mind if the date part can't be solved.

Comment: Depending on Excel Version:  `=INDEX(A1:A5,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(A1:A5)*ROW(A1:A5),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,SUM(--ISNUMBER(A1:A5))))))`, possibly with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: Early versions may require: `=INDEX(A1:A5,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(A1:A5)*ROW(A1:A5),N(IF(1, ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,SUM(--ISNUMBER(A1:A5))))))))` but I don't recall when this construct was no longer needed for returning an array of rows to the INDEX function.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: The AGGREGATE part returns {1;3;4;5} i.e. the row numbers of the 'matches' in both cases.

Comment: Exactly.  That is why it is wrapped by the INDEX function, to return the values in those rows.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: I need the formula to evaluate to `{1;3;44644;5}`. Your complete formula evaluates to `1`, while the `AGGREGATE` part evaluates to `{1;3;4;5}` (the matching rows) which altogether is close but not it. Also, when I copy the formula down, it skips the 3 showing e.g. in `G1:G5`, `{1;44644;5;0;0}`.

Comment: In earlier versions, you need to enter it as an array. And also, depending on how early a version, you may need to use the second variation. If you want to enter it in a single cell non-array, change the `k` argument to `rows($A$1:$A1)` and fill down. Be sure to also change `A1:A5` to `$A$1:$A$5`

Comment: Here's a variation on the formula offered by @RonRosenfeld.  It uses MODE.MULT, which has been available in Excel starting with version 2010 - `=INDEX(A1:A5,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5),(ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1)+1)*{1,1})))))`.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: I forgot how to enter an array formula in a range: I was CSE-confirming it in the first cell and then copying down when I should have selected the range with the first cell active, click in the formula bar, and then CSE-confirm. The result of the first formula is correct (nothing needed to be changed), while the second one returns VALUE# errors (probably too old since I'm using Office 2019). I would like you to consider wrapping it up into an answer since it was educational and is very closely connected with what I am looking for.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easy through formulae because Excel can *not* distinguish between say 44644 being an integer or meant to be a date unless you look at formatting of the cel. The only reasonable way of doing this that I can think of is to use [`CELL()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf), as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30778620/9758194) older post here on SO. It can't return an array correctly on its own so I came up with the following using `BYROW()`:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,BYROW(SEQUENCE(5,,0),LAMBDA(a,CELL("format",OFFSET(A1,a,0))="G"))*ISNUMBER(A1:A5))
```

This would work to filter out the dates (given the format in your data) since the cells that are *not* formatted as date would return "G" ('General', see the link to the ms-documentation). My limited testing suggested that this would work to filter out *dates* from the equation as per the question.

---

**Note:** To be more specific, you can exclude any cells that have this specific formatting ('mm/dd/yyyy') you have shown, from the equation through:

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,BYROW(SEQUENCE(5,,0),LAMBDA(a,LEFT(CELL("format",OFFSET(A1,a,0)))<>"D"))*ISNUMBER(A1:A5))
```

---

**EDIT**: The above solution would be ms365 exclusive. For Excel 2019, one way to do this is:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5),A1:A5,""))&"</s></t>","//s")
```

- It's an CSE-entered formula. If done correctly the returned array would be `{1;2;44644;3}`;
- We could also use `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,A1:A5)&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]")` however, since `TEXTJOIN()` has a limit I thought it would be wise to proces any non-number into an empty string beforehand;
- There is no way (I can think of) to exclude the dates in this version of Excel.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a solution for Office 2019? A solution without the date issue solved is also welcome.

Comment: @VBasic2008, well I edited in a very crude way of doing this in Excel-2019.

Answer (score 2):

365

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,ISNUMBER(-TEXT("1/1/"&A1:A5,"e/m/d")))
```

or older version:

```
=N(OFFSET(A1,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(-TEXT("1/1/"&A1:A5,"e/m/d")),ROW(1:5)-1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(-TEXT("1/1/"&A1:A5,"e/m/d"))))),))
```

Comment: Great. It'll take some time to understand it. Could you add some explanations or possibly 'translate' it for another range e.g. `B11:B20` so I could easier figure out how it works?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Use TEXT to convert dates, and use negative signs to exclude unqualified date values. The formula is not rigorous, because the numerical range is [1,31]. If the questioner can give the excluded date range, the formula will be easy.English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative via XML Spreadsheet udf**

Though the question shows the `excel-formula` tag, you might consider to use a user-defined function analyzing the column's `Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)` or simply `Range.Value(11)` xml content equivalent.

This approach benefits from the fact that the relevant data types of your question are **explicitly distinguished** between "Number" and "DateTime" formats.

As the resulting *xml content* includes namespace definitions like "ss:" I preferred to use late bound **MsXml2** for node extraction. *- Afaik namespacing can't be applied in `FilterXML` (a possible work-around would be reduce the whole content via split and replace any namespaces to allow this, too)*.

The following example udf assumes a 1-column range input (without further error handling) and gets all "real" numbers via a node select `Set cells = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ss:Cell[ss:Data/@ss:Type='Number']")`.

```
Function Nums(rng As Range)
'[0]Get Value(11)
    Dim s As String
    s = rng.value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)   ' or: rng.Value(11)
'[1]Set xml document to memory
    Dim xDoc As Object: Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
'[2]Add namespaces
    xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
    "xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' " & _
    "xmlns:ht='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'"
'[3]Get cells with Data/@Type "Number"
    If xDoc.LoadXML(s) Then            ' load wellformed string content
        Dim cell As Object, cells As Object
        Set cells = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ss:Cell[ss:Data/@ss:Type='Number']") ' XPath using namespace prefixes
        Dim tmp(): ReDim tmp(1 To cells.Length, 1 To 1)
        For Each cell In cells
            Dim i as long: i = i + 1
            tmp(i, 1) = cell.Text
        Next cell
        '[4]return 1-column array
        Nums = tmp
    End If
End Function
```

**Example call**

- In tabular Excel e.g. `Nums(A1:A5)` (resulting in a spill range if you dispose of dynamic array feature, otherwise via CSE), or
- via VBA e.g.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")
    Dim results
    results = Nums(rng)
    rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = results
```

Comment: Your alternatives are always refreshing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, I don't know of a reliable method of determining if an entry is a date type, since dates in Excel are stored as numbers.

Since you have also written that excluding the dates is not an absolute requirement, here are several formulas that will work depending on your version of Excel.

**O365**

```
C1: =FILTER(A1:A5,ISNUMBER(A1:A5))
```

*results will spill down*

**Earlier versions of Excel**

```
E1: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$5)*ROW(A1:$A$5),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,SUM(--ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$5)))))),"")
```

*entered as an array formula (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> over a range large enough to include all the results)*

```
G1: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$5)*ROW($A$1:$A$5),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

*entered as a **normal** formula, then fill down until you start returning blanks*

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. `AGGREGATE` is kind of essential when dealing with arrays in old Office versions.